# When converting video through ffmepg show error

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert video through ffmepg but its show this error
"Error initializing output stream 1:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #1:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height".
Its working fine on my system but facing the issue on server.

```
Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: qt
        encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 426x240, q=-1--1, 400 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 90k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2019-07-15T08:22:53.000000Z
          handler_name    : Core Media Video
          encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
        Side data:
          cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 428000/0/400000 buffer size: 600000 vbv_delay: -1
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2019-07-15T08:22:53.000000Z
          handler_name    : Core Media Audio
          encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
    [libx264 @ 0x6501780] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
    Error initializing output stream 1:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #1:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or heigh
```

Comment: Need to show your command and the **complete** log. Otherwise we have to make guesses.